# fullcalendar with long text in slot

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Using fullcalendar I see that usually slots texture consist of time and top and object title below.
If there is a way to replace them?

Also in some cases text in title of slot is too long and this text is truncated. If there is a way some slots to show with bigger in width or height,
maybe alwayasa or maybe when mouse is over slot?

Answer (score 1):

For long texts use this css: (it will make your title fill all the event square)

```
.fc-event .fc-content span{
    display: block;
}
```

If you want to change the *title text* use the **event** **property**:

```
title: your_text_here,
```

If you want to add a *window* when you pass the mouse over the event use this **event property**:

```
tooltip: ('<div class="tooltip_title">' + 'title' + '</div>' + '<div>' + '10:00 to 12:00'+ '<br>' +' doing this' + '</div>')
```